# UWP x:bind two-way binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

Objective: Create two text boxes bound to the same object with two-way binding, so that if I update the text in one, I see the *other* one automatically show the text I'm entering, and vise-versa.  I'd also like to see the same text appear in a text block (read only, one-way binding).  I need to use the x:bind syntax, not Binding syntax

Here's what I have so far, which isn't working:

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Foo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Foo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Foo, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public string Foo {get; set;}
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you initialize Foo to a value, does it get set anywhere on the View?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I eventually had to do.  I had no idea so much baggage came with two-way binding.

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

C#:

```
 namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public TextModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            ViewModel = new TextModel();
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class TextModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string foo = "hello";
        public string Foo
        {
            get => foo;

            set
            {
                foo = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Foo"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's not a matter of Two-Way Binding specifically.  XAML only knows if something is updated if it's a DependencyProperty or you use the INotifyPropertyChanged event.  For a general property like you had in your initial post, it would never update the UI as no notification is sent by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Any binding will only be updated in the UI if it's notified of a change, there's two ways to do that.  Either you need to make your `Foo` property a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview) or have your page implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (also called out in the dependency property doc).